Download speed on Firefox very slow
I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a Lenovo X1 ThinkPad.
I have a 16Mbit/s DSL connection and am behind a Vodafone EasyBox.
Since a while, Firefox is quite slow and I realized that a Speedcheck from my ISP shows me 0.13 Mbit/s download rate.
The ISP tells me that the connection is good "up to the router".
I have then checked the same speedtest with LAN, WLAN, with another computer, with and without LAN cable connector, even with a different browser.
As it seems, on my same computer, the speedtest shows me 11Mbit/s download rate when on Chrome.
So I have completely de-installed and re-installed latest FF 125. But the issue persists.
I have tried the FF settings

unchecked 'Use recommended performance settings'
Connection settings -> Use no proxy

But nothing helps so far.
Are there any other settings that might bring Firefox back to normal performance?
